# Paint.getTextBounds() returning negative bounds

Tags: android, paint

I am trying to find the text which is being clicked in a canvas displayed on a imageview. I've overridden the on touch on imageview.So this is the approach I used. I've stored all the x,y coordinates on the canvas where I've displayed text along with the text and Paint. when a Motion_event.ACTION_DOWN is triggered. I get the event coordinates and check if the event coordinates are with in the text bounds. Here is the code snippet.

```
                    float  xRatio=(float)mTempBitmap.getWidth()/(float)mEditImageView.getWidth();
                    float yRatio= (float)mTempBitmap.getHeight()/(float)mEditImageView.getHeight();

                    mEditImageView.setImageBitmap(mTempBitmap);
                    for (TextItem textItem : mTextItemStack) {
                        Rect tempRect = new Rect();
                        textItem.getPaint().getTextBounds(textItem.getTextContent(), 0, textItem.getTextContent().length() - 1, tempRect);
                        tempRect.offset(textItem.getXCoordinate(), textItem.getYCoordinate());
                        if (tempRect.contains((int)(event.getX()*xRatio), (int) (event.getY()*yRatio))) {
                            mtextItemInFocus = textItem;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

But the problem arises in the getTextBounds() call.Here is the Doc for getTextBounds.

> [Return in bounds (allocated by the caller) the smallest rectangle that encloses all of the characters, with an implied origin at (0,0).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

But I get negative bounds as a result. Clearly my understanding of the getTextBounds is wrong. Please correct me. I welcome alternate approach for doing the same.

Comment: Do you mean the `top` bound is negative, or all of them are?

Comment: i suggest using `android.text.Layout` for drawing text / detecting text boundaries

Comment: @MikeM. yes top is negative

Comment: The origin at (0, 0) is the left point of the baseline of the text. Since the y-axis is oriented so that upward is negative, the `top` bound will be negative. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeM. gotcha Thank you.